# Connecting to localhost via iPhone while connected to a hotspot

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, localhost, hotspot

I need some help accessing a server that I have running on my mac. So basically my setup consists of mac on which I'm running my server and also using XCode to run the app on an iPhone connected via USB. And then both this iPhone and the mac are on the same WiFi network which is a personal hotspot that I have running on a different iPhone.

I'm trying to access localhost from the iPhone by basically using my mac's IP address and the right port: `http://IPADDRESS:PORT/`, however this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas as to what may be going on here and potential workarounds or solutions. Connecting to a non-hotspot, traditional WiFi network is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you have it set up correctly; I am doing it right now. Remember that you have to bind the server to `0.0.0.0` — not `127.0.0.1` — if you want to connect from non-localhost IPs. Also check your system firewall.

If you're still having trouble, Tailscale is another solution that may help — https://tailscale.com

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) as a solution, this will create a secure tunnel and expose the service running on your Mac through a url.

You'll need to create an account and retrieve your auth token.

You can then install it using Homebrew by running in Terminal: `brew cask install ngrok`

Once installed, connect your account by typing into Terminal: `ngrok authtoken [auth_token]`

To start a tunnel, type into Terminal: `ngrok [protocol] [port number]`

For example, to start a tunnel to a HTTP server running on your mac: `ngrok http 80` (or `ngrok http 443` for HTTPS)

If its a custom TCP protocol use: `ngrok tcp [port]` (or `ngrok tls [port]` if using TLS)

This will then give you a URL to use in your app. On free accounts, the URL will change on each restart, paid accounts get a static URL option.

---

If you don't have Homebrew, download it from and follow instructions on: https://ngrok.com/download